# How do you do things according to the thrown value?

Tags: javascript, try-catch, catch-block

MDC says to do this, but also says that they think it's just a FireFox extension:

live code: http://jsfiddle.net/vQsUX/

```
try {  
   throw("InvalidNameException");  
}  

catch (e if e == "InvalidNameException") {
   document.write(e)  
}  

catch (e if e == "InvalidIdException") {
   document.write(e)  
}  

catch (e if e == "InvalidEmailException") {  
   document.write(e)  
}
```

How can I do a similar thing that'll work for all browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just catch the object and evaluate it in a single `catch` block:

```
try {
  // stuff
}
catch (exc) {
  if (exc === "InvalidNameException") {
    // do something
  }
  else if (exc === "whatever") {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

Since exceptions are just objects, and you can `throw` anything you like, you can always develop your own more elaborate exception structures. Exception objects can have code to run, numeric keys, whatever you need. That said, I've never found much use for an elaborate exception mechanism in Javascript; it just doesn't seem to come up much. Nevertheless:

```
function riskyCodeHere() {
  // scary dangerous things
  if (badThings()) {
    throw {
      key: 207,
      badnessLevel: "terrible",
      toString: function() {
        return "Things have gotten " + this.badnessLevel;
      }
    };
  }
}

// ...

try {
   riskyCodeHere();
}
catch (b) {
   switch (b.key) {
     case 207: console.log(b.toString()); 
     // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: +1, nice! first time to see this use of throw! something really "bad" is happening up there! :-)

Comment: Thanks! May I ask what the `toString: function(){}` helps with?

Comment: Oh that was just an example; it might be useful for debugging purposes or something.  An exception class might provide its own logging API or something like that too.  The point was to show that you can `throw` an object of any size or shape.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a `switch` statement:

```
try {  
   throw("InvalidNameException");  
}  
catch (e) {
    switch (e.toString()) {
        case "InvalidNameException":
            document.write(e);
            break;

        case "InvalidIdException":
            document.write(e);
            break;

        case "InvalidEmailException":
            document.write(e);
            break;
    }
}
```

It's not as pretty as the Firefox extension, but it does much the same thing.

Note that the above is a fairly literal translation of your original. Exceptions don't have to be strings, so you can do more interesting things than a switch if they're going to be more interesting exceptions:

```
try {
    throw new MyNiftyException(...);
}
catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof MyNiftyException) {
        // Do something related to that
    }
    // etc
}
```